# Detect if ringtone finished playing

Tags: java, android, ringtone

I want to detect when a ringtone has finished playing but the Android `Ringtone` class does not have an `OnCompletionListener` as the `MediaPlayer` class has. 
Specifically, and in practice, I am playing a ringtone in the following way:

```
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                getApplicationContext(), soundUri);
r.play();
```

And I want to catch the on completion event of the ringtone player (if it even launches this event...) as one can do with the `MediaPlayer` class. I am aware that the `Ringtone` class provides the method `isPaying` but I don't like the solution of periodically checking it until it returns false... On the other side, with the `MediaPlayer` class, one is able to detect if the player has finished playing something, in a much more clean way, by setting the `OnCompletionListener` callback:

```
final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(filepath);
player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        player.release();
     }
});
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

So, how can I do the same using the ringtone manager? Is it even possible? Or is the solution of periodically checking the `Ringtone.isPlaying`, until it returns false, the best one???